# Assert that element from List<webelement> contains some text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, assert, assertion

I'm not sure how can I assert that I have a list of webelements where each webelement has the text `inside`, And I want to verify that on this list of webelements exists some text.

I not sure how this should looks assertion in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple get stream, map to string (text) and check if any matches:

```
boolean anyMatch = webelements.stream()
  .map(WebElement::getText)
  .anyMatch(text -> "inside".equals(text));
```

To be safe filter out null's and trim:

```
boolean anyMatch = webelements.stream()
  .map(WebElement::getText)
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .map(String::trim)
  .anyMatch(text -> "inside".equals(text));
```

Comment: Thanks, for reply. I would like to put it in assertion, so should I use it in assertTrue?

Comment: @pejas Awesome Answer (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public boolean isElementsContainsProvidedText(String text){

    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("your_xpath_for_list"));

    return elements.stream().anyMatch(e->e.gettext().trim().equals(text));     

}
```